# Conflicting arguments to generic parameter when trying to draw an Array of multiple views as Protocols

Tags: generics, swiftui, protocols

I am trying to use a protocol to draw multiple items in a VStack. When adding one item to the array of protocols, it draws as expected. When adding multiple items from different structs conforming to the same protocol, I get the following error:

Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'BaseView' ('ImageType' vs. 'StringType' vs. 'ImageType' vs. 'StringType')

here is the main code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView<BaseView:ProtocolWithView>: View {
    var protocols:[BaseView]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach( protocols, id:\.self ){ aProtocol in
                aProtocol.baseView
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    let stringType = StringType(string: "This is a preview")
    let imageType = ImageType(imgName: "img")
//     return ContentView(protocols: [imageType] ) <-- draws as expected
    return ContentView(protocols: [imageType, stringType] ) // <-- error: Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'BaseView' ('ImageType' vs. 'StringType' vs. 'ImageType' vs. 'StringType')
}
```

here is the protocol and structs conforming to the protocols:

```
protocol ProtocolWithView:Identifiable, Hashable{
    associatedtype BaseView: View
    var id:UUID { get set }
    @ViewBuilder var baseView:BaseView { get }
}

struct ImageType:ProtocolWithView{
    let imgName:String
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @ViewBuilder var baseView: some View{
        Image( imgName )
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }

struct StringType:ProtocolWithView{
    var string:String
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    var baseView: some View{
        Text( string )
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, thanks
Reza

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose for `ProtocolWithView` , but it is bad for the SwiftUI views to be passed in an array.  However, you can have an array of `ProtocolWithView` that has a BaseView of type `AnyView`

Comment: The idea is ver simple. I need to display a series of different items with different views. Using a protocol that returns a view will make that possible. An AnyView can be used, as a last resort, but that is not recommended method by apple.